# Ignore folder when build using Middleman App

Tags: ruby, middleman

I want to ignore `samples/` folder when build. I used this

```
configure :build do
  activate :asset_hash, :ignore => [/^samples\//]
end
```

It didn't work and that folder was still included during build process. Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following code to your config.rb file:

```
ignore 'samples/*'
```

`#ignore` accepts regular expressions as well. See [the specs](https://www.relishapp.com/middleman/middleman-core/docs/ignoring-paths).